# Python sqlalchemy "not all arguments converted during bytes formatting"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I want to insert some data to my database with using sqlalchemy module. But when I try it it gives me error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting` on `query = query % args` string in `MySQLdb\cursors.py`. I tried to use pymysql instead of mysqldb and it gives the same error.

This is the code:

```
myquery = "INSERT INTO some(id, name, info, det_info, class, cluster, logo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

for row in result:
    connection1.execute(myquery, (None, row['name'], row['info'], row['det_info'], row['class'], row['cluster'], row['logo']))
```

I tried different variations of sending parameters: with squares and without, all give the same result.
I tried to add these strings to cursors.py:

```
print(query)
print('----@@@@----@@@@----@@@@----@@@@----@@@@----@@@@----@@@@----')
print(args)
```

And it gives this:

`b'INSERT INTO some(id, name, info, det_info, class, cluster, logo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'`

And this:

`(b'NULL', b"'\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd1\x82'", b"'\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\'", b"'Institute'", b"'Inte'", b"'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbe'", b"'1.png'")`

So, my guess that the problem can be in "(?, ?, ...)" and how it will be changed by arguments during % operation. But I don't know am i right or not and how to fix the problem.

Comment: Your DB-API library uses some other placeholder other than `?`, likely `%s` (don't mix that with manual string formatting, though).

Comment: @IljaEverilä I changed "?" to "%s" and now it works, thanks, but is it ecranized now? If I will do something which can be SQLinjected - how can I do it safe?

Comment: Unless you used the `%` operator to format the values to the string manually, instead of passing the argument tuple as the 2nd argument to `execute()` as before, you're still safe. The point is to pass the arguments to your driver library to handle.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments to the question, different implementations of the Python DB-API can choose to use different [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)s. For example, it appears that your chosen tool implements the "format" paramstyle (`%s`) but you were trying to use the "qmark" (`?`) style.

However, since you have tagged this question for SQLAlchemy, consider using SQLAlchemy's `.text` method to process your queries using its own paramstyle ("named") and let SQLAlchemy take care of translating it to the native style of the DB-API layer. That way, no matter which back-end you are hitting, your parameter queries will always look the same (and have the convenience of named parameters to boot).

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

query = sa.text("INSERT INTO student (lastname, firstname) VALUES (:ln, :fn)")
values = {'ln': 'Thompson', 'fn': 'Gord'}
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(query, values)
```